# Zero Inflated Poisson Regression in SPSS

Tags: regression, spss, poisson

Is possible to perform a Zero Inflated Poisson Regression using SPSS for Windows (version 22 or higher)? Could anyone please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available (with quite a few options) via the STATS ZEROINFL (Analyze > Generalized Linear Models > Zero-inflated count models) extension command.  This requires the (free) R Essentials.  Once that is installed, you can install this command from Utilities > Extension Bundles > Download and Install Extension Bundles.

See
https://developer.ibm.com/predictiveanalytics/downloads/
if you don't already have the Ressentials installed for detailed instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable reply. Any further suggestions or tutorial are more than welcome.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a goo tutorial reference at hand.  You might also want to look at negative binomial models.